# Retrieve Applied Template Page Ranges in DocuSign Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi, e-signature

I am attempting to migrate/manipulate completed envelopes in DocuSign. Situation is a little interesting as the goal is to receive the completed signed documents (which are often combined pdf's with multiple templates applied) and split them up into component documents by their templates.

Documents sent with [template matching](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=far1578456612069.html&_LANG=enus) work great as the return query outlined [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/list/) produces a json response with the following node with clear start and end pages.

```
{
  "templates": [
    {
      "templateId": "sample string 1",
      "name": "sample string 2",
      "documentId": "sample string 3",
      "documentName": "sample string 4",
      "applied": "sample string 5",
      "templateMatch": {
        "matchPercentage": "sample string 1",
        "documentStartPage": "sample string 2",
        "documentEndPage": "sample string 3"
      },
      "uri": "sample string 6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Envelopes where instead templates are manually applied don't have the nice response - but it does appear that page information is at some point collected. IE this screenshot shows users can indicate on what pages templates begin - [Users indicating template pages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEuIC.png) Though this data doesn't appear to be available anywhere post-envelope creation. The page numbers are able to be [supplied](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/applytodocument/) but not retrieved it seems. DocuSign's documentation doesn't appear to have anything but there are sections of the documentation with errors as is. Is anyone familiar with the described functionality?

So far since nothing is described for this purpose in the documentation I've tried a variety of other template information calls with various included query parameters. I'd expect that "applied" templates would return page information similar to the "matched" templates. Templates are defined with page ranges in place so knowing the starting page should indicate the closing page. Edge case would be users manually moving fields around.

I've also tried some alternate methods for the overall solution by using "tabID"s in found on the pages to match back to templates but there is very little information on correlations between ID's (if any) and my tests didn't seem to reveal any useful info.

Comment: Remember that templates can also be `included` in an envelope vs `applied` to a document in the envelope. If a template is included then the template's documents (and their tabs, recipients, etc) are added into the envelope. **Summary:** I don't know how realistic your task is... Also remember you can download the documents from envelopes as separate documents (or combined into one big PDF).

Comment: @LarryK yeah my tab approach initially relied on using the tabID's from any of the known templates in the envelope. Either from a lack of understanding of the ID's on my part or an issue with the users actions in initiating the envelopes the tabID's on the documents do not match values from the templates.

My conclusion was also that I don't believe its a possible task without major modification of the user's behavior. But that would not resolve importing prior completed envelopes only for day forward.